# Scrollview generate error while scrolling at last end or to the top of scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am creating a custom cell in `uitableview` dynamically. And this generates `uiscrollview` automatically as number of cells increases but when I scroll to the extreme up or extreme down i.e. at end or start of `uiscrollview`.

`uiscrollview` generate error while scrolling at last end or to the top of scroll .

Comment: can you provide the code and error

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 6 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: may be related to cell reuse...but not getting exactly

Comment: Probably it's error in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Do you use array to store cell data?

Comment: actually i am storing json result in array and then using it in custom cell for displaying in labels

Comment: @GarimaPaliwal I think your array has less items than you're trying to display

Comment: We're not magicians, please provide code :)